# Helmholtz equation in Laplace equation of cylinder

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a cylinder of height $H$ and radius $a$. I am about to find $u(\rho, \phi, z)$ that solves the equation $$\Delta u = 0 $$
with the given boundary conditions

$$u(a, \phi, z) =0,$$
$$u(\rho, \phi, 3) =0,$$
$$u(\rho, \phi, 0) =f(\rho, \phi).$$

The problem here is not the process but instead the properties of the Helmholtz equation I get.
Seperating the variables I get:
$$\Delta G(z)-\lambda G(z)=0$$
$$\Delta w(\rho,\phi)+\lambda w(\rho,\phi)=0$$

The second equation is a Helmholtz equation. I know the properties of the Helmholtz equation. But can I safely from the second equation with the boundary condition $u(a, \phi, z) =0$ know that $\lambda > 0$? Because the function about the surface when $z=0$ is not zero, that makes me confused.

Because in the case when I have disc (not a cylinder) with the same boundary condition at radius $a$ I know from the properties of Helmholtz equation that $\lambda >0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $w$ is not-identically-zero function with zero boundary values in some domain $D$, and $\Delta w+\lambda w=0$ holds in $D$, then you can conclude $\lambda>0$.  Proof:
$$0 = \int_D w(\Delta w+\lambda w) = \int_D (-|\nabla w|^2 + \lambda w^2)$$
where the first term was integrated by parts. If $\lambda\le 0$, we have a contradiction: the integral on the right is negative.